# How do I use SVGs for background images on buttons in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, create-react-app

First timer on stack overflow so I'll try my best.

I'm trying to dynamically add SVGs as background images for my buttons.

Created react app using create-react-app.
I have 3~ files in question: poland.svg, Flag.jsx and exampleComponent.jsx

---

exampleComponent.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import Flag from './Flag.jsx';

const exampleComponent = (props) => {
  const backgroundImage = {
    backgroundImage: `url(${Flag(props.nation)})`
  }

  return(
    <button style={backgroundImage}>
      <div />
    </button>
  )
}

export default exampleComponent;
```

---

Flag.jsx

```
import Poland from './poland.svg';
import US from './us.svg';

const Flag = (nation) => {
  let path = "";

  if (nation === "Poland") path = Poland;
  else if (nation === "US") path = US;

  return path;
}

export default Flag;
```

---

poland.svg

```
<svg
    height="100%"
    width="100%"
>
    <defs />
    <rect fill="#ffffff" width="100%" height="50%" />
    <rect transform="translate(0, 50px)" fill="#ff0000" width="100%" height="50%" />
</svg>
```

I'm getting the file path /static/media/poland.49b43928.svg
When I inspect the element in chrome the correct file path is shown but the SVG isn't being loaded!

IM STILL A NOOB! so please be harsh! ;D

Comment: poland.svg is not valid because it's missing the SVG namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Update! So the file was being sent in XML format.. I wish I knew more to explain the details but all I did to fix this was add:
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"

to the svg tags like so:

```
<svg
    height="100%"
    width="100%"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
>
    <defs />
    <rect fill="#ffffff" width="100%" height="50%" />
    <rect transform="translate(0, 50px)" fill="#ff0000" width="100%" height="50%" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the svg files are similar, there may be a problem with matching the

```
<use xlink ID:href="#xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx"/>,
```

where xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx is the ID, it must be unique for each file.

See the link, it may help

https://github.com/SilverFox70/svg-react-loader

Comment: Thank you for the fast response! :D I'll give it a shot!